# OpenGL ES indices issue

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am new to OpenGL ES and I need to know how we use the indices in that I didn't understand the numbers we used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ,the indices are used to describe in what order the vertices should be drawn.
This is usefull when you have to draw an object which is consisted by many vertices but many of them are  the same points.

So for example  when you want to draw a square with glDrawElements(with indices) you have

```
//vertices
-1,-1,0,  //0 bottom left
-1,1,0,   //1 top left
1,1,0,    //2 top right
1,-1,0    //3 bottom right

//indices
0         //0 bottom left
1         //1 top left
2         //2 top right
2         //2 top right
3         //3 bottom right
0         //0 bottom left
```

In the other hand if you want to draw a square with glDrawArrays(without indices) you have

```
 //vertices
-1,-1,0,  //0 bottom left
-1,1,0,   //1 top left
1,1,0,    //2 top right
1,1,0,    //2 top right
1,-1,0    //3 bottom right
-1,-1,0,  //0 bottom left
```

Answer (score -1):

[This article](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/01/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-13/)
 this may help you get an idea about indices. In code we use this structure:

```
const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},//0
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},//1
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}},//2
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}},//3
    {{1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},//4
    {{1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},//5
    {{-1, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}},//6
    {{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}//7
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    // Front
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    // Back
    4, 6, 5,
    4, 7, 6,
    // Left
    2, 7, 3,
    7, 6, 2,
    // Right
    0, 4, 1,
    4, 1, 5,
    // Top
    6, 2, 1, 
    1, 6, 5,
    // Bottom
    0, 3, 7,
    0, 7, 4    
};
```

Comment: So you've posted a whole lot of vertices and indices. Care to actually explain what they are and what they do? The link is fine, but you might want to at least summarize the content here so the answer is self-contained.

Comment: ya.I will explain him if he requests

Comment: in comments I mentioned him the numbers.

Comment: Thanks user1217862 now I understood by reading the link.But there is a lot to study.This link clears all my issues in open GLES